# How to show/hide component on button click in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a table, the column headings - buttons. When I click on them should show the filter. Filter is a component. Right now I show filter like that

```
<button class="filter-btn" (click)="toggleFilter='category'">Category</button>
<filterbox [elements]="filters.categories *ngIf="toggleFilter=='category'"></filterbox>
```

Can I show/hide filterbox component without variable "toggleFilter" i.e button click directly show/hide component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can toggle the `hidden` state like:

```ts
<button class="filter-btn" (click)="filter.hidden = !filter.hidden">Category</button>
<filterbox #filter [elements]="filters.categories></filterbox>
```